# Remove extra delimiters created by using characters within a delimited file with Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a delimited file exported with pipe as the delimiter by someone who didn't use a text qualifier and the text contains pipe characters. There should be 13 columns.

Additional columns have been created in several lines. Some 3, some 4. So, it's not the same number of additional columns created.

The delimiters are fine up till the text/column after the 10th pipe and the text/columns after the last two pipes. I want to replace the extra pipe characters after the 10th pipe and before the last two pipes with spaces regardless of whether it is 1 or more pipes in one go using a Regex pattern.

I have tried this:

```
^([^|]*)(?!(?:\|[^|\r\n]*){12}$)((?:\|[^|\r\n]*){10})(?:(\|)([^|\r\n]*))((?:\|[^|\r\n]*){2})$
```

replace with `$1$2$4$5`.

This only worked for where there were 14 columns. Lines with a larger number of columns are not matched.

Here's a line with more than 14 columns:

```
5070599047|SA|03/31/2023 00:00:00|04/03/2023 00:00:00|23121|152|65642.950000|0|0|XP-OFS-222761665|ZIB|BRH|NPAU|31-03-2023|749542|30271246.390000|342
```

The result I need:

```
5070599047|SA|03/31/2023 00:00:00|04/03/2023 00:00:00|23121|152|65642.950000|0|0|XP-OFS-222761665|ZIB BRH NPAU 31-03-2023 749542|30271246.390000|342
```

I need to remove all pipes after ZIB and before `|30271246.390000|342` and keep the text in that space. I also need a pattern that will work for lines with more than 13 columns regardless of the additional number of columns to reduce them all to 13 columns.

Comment: "I want to replace the extra pipe characters after the 10th pipe and before the last two pipes regardless of whether it is 1 or more pipes with one Regex pattern" Is pretty vague..... Can you add an example of expected output ?

Comment: When I read this, I think you mean to remove the `|` from the third argument in https://regex101.com/r/XoFzU1/1 ?

Comment: @Luuk I have updated the request with the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: You wrote, "I want to replace the extra pipe characters ... with one Regex pattern." What pattern? Your example suggests you wish to replace each pipe character (that is to be replaced) with a space. In future, please simplify your question as much as possible. There's no reason to 16 pipes rather than just a few, or to have `"XP-OFS-222761665"` rather than, say, `"ABC"`. You can adapt the results to your needs.

Comment: You say "I want to replace the extra pipe characters" but you don't say *what* you want to replace them with - please clarify. Also, why 1 operation? Why not several? And please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: @cary that sentence means I want a solution(regex pattern) that will work for any number of columns above 13.

Comment: @bohemian I have added my desired result/expected output in the request above. Seen that?

Comment: Why have you reverted my edit that formatted the question to more clearly distiguish code from narrative?

Comment: @adrian I'm new to Stack Overflow so I'm not sure what you mean but I edited the question based on the comments and feedback.

Comment: Look at the changes made by @Jan, their changes are very similar to those I did. Then your edit reverted it all. Click on the `edited NNN mins ago` link just below the question and you can see all the revisions of the question.

Comment: Do you wish to replace each pipe character (`"|"`) after the 10th and before the second-to-last with a space character? If so, you should say that, without confusing it with how you think it should done (e.g., replacing a match with something like `$1$2$4$5`).

Comment: @cary I have reverted to edits made by Jan as suggested by Adrian. I will do better with future questions but I still need help with this one. I'll take a look at the demo. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this `^(?:[^|]*\|){10}\K|[^|]*\K\|(?=.*(?:\|[^|]*){2}$)` only highlights a single pipe character on the line of the text I'm trying to fix in my notepad++ file.

Comment: Emmanuel, I'm afraid I don't know Notepad++, but maybe a reader who does can help with this. You can see from my "Demo" link in my answer that three pipes are matched. You said only one pipe was matched in Notepad++. Was that the 11th pipe? Are you looking at a table that is similar to the first one [here](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2020/using-regex-to-find-and-replace-text-in-notepad/) and selected "Replace All"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I can see three pipes matched in your demo. In notepad++ it matches each occurrence of a pipe, one at a time. So, when you click "find next", it highlights a pipe. Clicking"find next" again, it highlights the next pipe in that line and on and on. It does this for every line, not just the lines with too many columns. Thanks for your help so far. And yes, that's what the dialog box looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The first 10 and last two pipes in each line are to be preserved. Each of the four others is to be replaced with a space. Each match of the following regular expression (with `g` and `m` flags<sup>1</sup> set) can be replaced with a space.

```
(?:^(?:[^|\r\n]*\|){10}[^|\r\n]*\K\||(?!^)\G[^|\r\n]*\K\|)(?=.*(?:\|[^|\r\n]*){2}$)
```

If there are 12 or fewer pipes no substitutions are made.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cAccVq/1)

---

Notepad++ uses the [Boost regex engine](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/regex/doc/introduction.html), which differs only slightly from the [PCRE engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), which is the one used at the "Demo" link. In particular, both support `\K` and `\G`. `\K` causes previously-matched tokens to be discarded from the match that is returned and resets the start of match to the current location in the string. `\G` sets the current position to be at the end of the previous match.

---

The expression can be broken down as follows.<sup>2</sup>

```
(?:             # begin non-capture group
  ^             # match the beginning of the string
  (?:           # begin a non-capture group
    [^|\r\n]*\| # match >= 0 characters other than '|', '\r' and '\n', then '|'
  )             # end the non-capture group
  {10}          # execute preceding non-capture group 10 times
  [^|\r\n]*     # match >= 0 characters other than '|', '\r' and '\n'
  \K            # discard previously-consumed tokens and reset start of match 
  \|            # match '|' 
  |             # or
  (?!^)         # negative lookahead asserts next character is not at the start of the string 
  \G            # sets the current position to be at the end of the previous match
  [^|\r\n]*     # match >= 0 characters other than '|', '\r' and '\n'
  \K            # discard previously-consumed tokens and reset start of match  
  \|            # match '|'
)               # end non-capture group
(?=             # begin the positive lookahead
  .*            # match >= 0 characters other than line terminators
  (?:           # begin a non-capture group
    \|[^|\r\n]* # match '|' then >= 0 characters other than '|', '\r' and '\n'
  )             # end the non-capture group
  {2}           # execute preceding non-capture group twice
  $             # match the end of the string
)               # end the positive lookahead
```

<sup>1. `g` causes the regex engine to make multiple matches, if possible. `m` causes `^` and `$` to represent end-of-line (rather than end-of-string) anchors, respectively.</sup>

<sup>2. Also, by hovering over each part of the expression at the link (the cursor, not you, yourself) one can obtain an explanation of its function.</sup>

Comment: The regular expression in this answer (`(?:^(?:[^|]*\|){10}[^|]*\K\||(?!^)\G[^|]*\K\|)(?=.*(?:\|[^|]*){2}$)`) does find the 4 `|` which can be replaced by a space. see: [screenshot of Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgqDC.png) with the `|` marked in red. (Note: I tested this using the 32-bits version 8.6 of Notepad++)

Comment: Hi @Luuk. That didn't work for the version I have but I tweaked it to this `^[^|\r\n]*(?!(?:\|[^|\r\n]*){12}$)(?:\|[^|\r\n]*){10}\K\||(?!^)\G[^|]*\K\|(?=.*(?=[^|\r\n]*(?:\|[^|]*){2}$))` and it's highlighting all four pipes now.

Comment: Very good, Emmanuel! Your change allows it to match multiple lines (since [^|] matches newlines). I've made the same change to the regex in my answer (changing each `[^|]` to `[^|\r\n]`). See the new "Demo".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not to sound like a broken record but thank you for your help once again. I'll upvote (not sure that's the right term) the answer. Hopefully it helps someone else in the future. Not enough rep for that it turns out.